# Can I pass cursor set from Java to Oracle Procedure using IN parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following block which sends the ref cursor to Proc

```
Procedure abc(c1  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
as 
begin
open c1 for
select 
fname,lname,cconttac from address;
end;
```

It is working smoothly , whenever procedure is being called in Java and cursor is being opened.

is it Possible to get cursor as IN parameter in procedure and open it for processing.

Comment: The answer is: Yes, it is possible, you can pass the cursor to another procedure as IN parameter.

Comment: btw that's not a block that sends a ref cursor to a procedure. It's a procedure.